# Energy Conservation and Speed of a Falling Satellite

Tags: integration, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

I've been given the following problem (admittedly on a homework sheet), which I've solved, but I feel there has to be a neater method of solving it:

> A satellite falls freely towards the Earth starting from rest at a distance R, much
>   larger than the Earth’s radius. Treating the Earth as a point of mass M, letting the time taken to reach the Earth be T, the distance of the satellite from the Earth at time t be r(t), with G the gravitational constant, working from the equation of energy conservation for the satellite, prove:
>
> $$\ T = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2} (\frac{R^3}{GM})^{1/2}$$

Working through this, I got this $ E = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2 - \frac{GMm}{r}$, where m is the mass of the satellite, for the equation of energy conservation (assuming no friction). This leads to a rather nasty integral when solving, which does indeed give the correct answer. However, the integral, namely $ \int\sqrt\frac{r}{Er+GMm}dr $ is incredibly annoying and time-consuming to solve, and seems out of character with the neatness of the other problems on the sheet. I was wondering if there's perhaps a better way of doing this, or indeed some clever trick to solve the integral. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: The fact that $R >> r_e$ is likely a simplifying factor in the problem.

Comment: The minus sign in the denominator should also be a plus sign.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, that's a typo, I'll correct it now

Comment: I know it's not in the spirit of the homework, but I want to point out that this is just a special case of Kepler's Third Law. Rather than solve a new integral from first principles every time one has a question about orbital mechanics, the "right" approach is to derive Kepler's laws and then apply them wherever you can. Generally speaking, Axiom -> Lemma -> Theorem is a saner way of life than insisting on Axiom -> Theorem.

Comment: @ChrisCutler, this isn’t an orbit, so Keplers Third Law is not useful here.

Comment: @Paul It **is** a degenerate orbit, where the minor axis is collapsed to zero. Or, if you insist, you can breathe sideways on the satellite to give its orbit a minor axis of 1 nanometer.

Comment: @ChrisCutler of course it _lies_ on a degenerate orbit, but it is only a fraction of 1 orbit.

Comment: @Paul It's an simple fraction, namely $1/2$. Every elliptical orbit spends half of its time approaching the primary and the other half receding. Any other fraction would violate time reversal symmetry. (Also please stop misspelling my name; it prevents notifications from reaching me.)

Comment: @ChrisCulter, it's actually 1/4, based on the conditions of the problem  (I apologize for the misspelling).

Comment: @Paul (Thanks!) I'm pretty sure it's 1/2, but it's not really necessary to hash that out here.